# Can we send mail to multiple recipients using LiveMailMessage in Windows Phone 8

Tags: email, windows-phone-8

My Windows Application requirement is to send mail to multiple recipients with or without attachments depending on specific scenario. As EmailComposeTask does not have an "Attach" property, I am going to use [MailMessage](http://www.geekchamp.com/marketplace/components/livemailmessage), which has an attachment property.
But can we send mail to multiple recipients using MailMessage?.
Also any other Mail API's available via Managed Nugets which have attach property as well sending to multiple recipients.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Anyone any idea on the same??..

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer..The answer is Yes. Check [this](http://tintamarre7.zoolbia.com/chan-5196209/all_p31.html) for further info on mail message.